# Argument error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments

I am trying to create a new project in Rails. But I am facing following error:

```
Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:25:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:329:in `new'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:329:in `paths'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:352:in `path'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:979:in `dirs'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:831:in `stubs'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find_by_path'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:189:in `try_activate'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/c192/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:6:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The command you are running to get this would be useful.

Comment: please add few more details

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason of _No MCVE: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers_.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link if you are new in rails

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
This is link for how to create rails project and more details here

Answer (score 0):

Command to create new rails project:

```
rails new project_name
```